# Python Pandas' stacked BarPlot by group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've a dataframe like this:

| DATE | VALUE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | 57 | A |
| 2021-02-11 | 34 | B |
| 2021-03-11 | 43 | A |
| 2021-04-11 | 15 | B |
| ... |  |  |

My question is how I could plot a bar graph, the mean monthly ordered by date of course and grouped by 'TYPE'

I'm using Pandas with this extract of code:

```
    df = df.set_index('DATE') 
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

    df = df.resample('M').mean()
    df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

I want to draw a stacked bar plot but I don't know how...

Comment: What do you mean with "grouped by 'TYPE'"?

Comment: I was looking for a barplot with stacked VALUE's for the two TYPE's (A/B) of my DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly but if you want to stack values by types with date as x-axis, I would use pivot (do not set index first):

```
df = df.pivot('DATE', 'TYPE', 'VALUE')
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

With the slightly edited table to show the stacking:

| DATE | VALUE | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | 57 | A |
| 2021-02-11 | 34 | A |
| 2021-02-11 | 12 | B |
| 2021-03-11 | 43 | A |
| 2021-04-11 | 15 | B |

You get the following:

[image]

Comment: THANKS! thats what I mean.